# Calculating determinant using eigenvalues (real and complex)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant, characteristic-polynomial

I was trying to find the eigenvalues for the following characteristic polynomial:

$$p_M(\lambda)=(\lambda^{4}+1)(\lambda^2-4)$$

For this I solved the equation $p_M=0$ and I found the following two real eigenvalues:

$$\lambda=2\ \vee \ \lambda=-2$$

and I also got the four complex eigenvalues from

$$\exp({i(\pi/4\ + k\pi/2}))$$

Multiplying all $6$ eigenvalues I got the answer that the determinant of the corresponding matrix must be $-4$. This is the product of the two real eigenvalues.

Is this coincidence? Or is the determinant always the product of the real eigenvalues?

Comment: Roots of $t^4+1$ are complex $8$-th roots of unity, so have absolute value $1$.

Comment: Note that the zero-th order term in the characteristic polynomial is equal to the determinant.

Answer (score 1):

No, the determinant is not always the product of the real eigenvalues.
Take the diagonal matrix (the Jordan form of a real matrix, if you want only real matrices)
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \cr 0 & 2i & 0 \cr 0 & 0 & -2i \end{pmatrix}.
$$
Here the characteristic polynomial is
$$
\chi_A(t)=(t^2 + 4)(t - 1).
$$

Comment: Note that it is the product of all eigenvalues, as $z$ and $\bar{z}$ always come in pairs for matrices with real entries, it is a real number anyways.

Comment: @k76u4vkweek547v7 Yes, it is a real number anyway. But the determinant here is $4$ and the product of real eigenvalues is $1$. This is different from each other.

Comment: Just pointing out that there is not reason to think that the determinant only involves real quantities.